# React object value decreased 2 times insead of 1

Tags: reactjs, object

so I'm facing a non logical problem!

I have an object and i'm trying to update a value nested too deep inside this object.The value is type of number. I want to decrease the number by one for click, but when i try to do this on that object it decreases by two for click.

This is my code:

```
const [newDhomatData, setNewDhomatData] = useState(() => {
const obj = { ...dhomatFirebase[0] };

for (let i = 1; i <= ditQendrimiArray.length; i++) {
 obj.muajt[`${muaj}`].datatDhomat[`dat${i}`][`${dataForSpecific.dhoma}`] -= 1; 
}
return obj;
});
```

And this is the object:

[image]

So for example when i run the code above the value of let's say `dhomCift` instead of being 44 it becomes 43!

The path of object is right but I have about 1 hour trying to solve this thing and it looks not logical because I'm decreasing the value of this object key by 1 every click but it get decreased by two.

Thanks very much if someone will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by a `StrictMode` component which is wrapping your application. You might find it in your main `App.js` file or in the `ReactDOM` render method.

Strict Mode enables additional development behaviors and warnings for the component tree inside it and causes some hooks to run twice.

More info about it [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode).

Comment: Thanks for answering but it is not the strict mode causing this problem because  problem occured on the first render.

Comment: I tried to remove strict mode and it worked!Thanks.But do you know does this means that i need to update my object in another way or Im updating it right?

Comment: Strict mode checks are run in development mode only, so they do not impact the production build, so it's not really a problem once you build your app. Alternatively, you can only put `<StrictMode>` around the components you want, instead of having it on the root component.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way of doing this without getting problems

```
const [newDhomatData, setNewDhomatData] = useState(() => {
const obj = {
  ...dhomatFirebase[0],
  muajt: {
    ...dhomatFirebase[0].muajt,
    qershor: {
      datatDhomat: {
        ...dhomatFirebase[0].muajt.qershor.datatDhomat,
        dat1: {
          ...dhomatFirebase[0].muajt.qershor.datatDhomat.dat1,
          dhomFamiljare:
            dhomatFirebase[0].muajt.qershor.datatDhomat.dat1.dhomFamiljare -
            1,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
return obj;
```

})

instead of updating the object after declaring it i can update the object on the time that i will declare it and it will give me the result that i want!

This may be helpfull to someone.